# Custom constructor in Luabind

Tags: lua, coroutine, luabind

I'm using Luabind to bind a C++ API to Lua. I have some objects that cannot be created directly, but rather must be created on another thread. I'm currently handling this by defining a "static" member called `create` that yields until the object is created:

```
luabind::class_<Foo>("Foo")
  .scope
  [
    luabind::def("create", &someCreateMethod, luabind::yield)
  ]
```

This works, but has the disadvantage of complicating the client API. For these classes, you cannot create them normally (e.g. `local f = Foo()`), but instead need to do `local f = Foo.create()`.

Is it possible to define a Luabind constructor that doesn't actually call the C++ constructor, but instead another function that returns the constructed object (and can yield in the meantime)? I've tried defining bindings for `__init` and `__call` (the latter under a `scope`, to define it on the class, not its instances), but I didn't have success with either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors in Luabind must be actual C++ class constructors. So you'll just have to deal with the slight API weirdness.

If all you're interested in is the ability to use `Foo` as a constructor method, then you can do this. Register your C++ class `Foo` as `FooLua` to Lua. Then, register this `someCreateMethod`, not as a member of `FooLua`, but as just a Lua free function called `Foo`. Thus, as far as the user is concerned, `Foo` is a constructor for the Lua class `Foo`.

Now, this will inhibit your ability to give `Foo` other static properties, like members and so forth. But you could accomplish that by using some direct Lua API coding. You can create an empty table `Foo` and create a metatable for it that forwards `__index` and `__newindex` calls to `FooLua`. Similarly, you can override this metatable's `__call` to forward the construction to `Foo.create`.

Comment: And there's no way, on either the C++ or the Lua side, to "fake" it with the `__call` operator either?

Comment: @Xtapolapocetl: Luabind stores C++ types as userdata, so Lua code cannot affect its metatables. You could poke a Luabind's metatables from C++, but really, this is such a minor issue that it's negligible. Indeed, if the syntax *really* bothers you, you could just call the object `FooInternal` with Luabind and just create a function `Foo` that calls the `FooInternal.create` function. The user can think that they're using a class called `Foo`.

Comment: @Xtapolapocetl: In addition to Nicol's comment, if you only use `Foo` to create objects (i.e. no other scope methods) you could even just do `Foo = Foo.create`.

Answer (score 0):

While luabind doesn't provide a straight-forward way of defining custom constructors, it is in fact possible with a bit of a hack:

```
template<typename T,auto TCnstrct,typename ...TArgs>
static void custom_constructor(luabind::argument const &self_, TArgs... args)
{
    using holder_type = luabind::detail::value_holder<T>;
    luabind::detail::object_rep* self = luabind::touserdata<luabind::detail::object_rep>(self_);

    void* storage = self->allocate(sizeof(holder_type));
    self->set_instance(new (storage) holder_type(nullptr,TCnstrct(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)));
}

template<typename T,auto TCnstrct,typename ...TArgs>
    static void define_custom_constructor(lua_State *l)
{
    auto *registry = luabind::detail::class_registry::get_registry(l);
    auto *crep = registry->find_class(typeid(T));
    assert(crep);
    auto fn = luabind::make_function(l,&custom_constructor<T,TCnstrct,TArgs...>);
    crep->get_table(l);
    auto o = luabind::object{luabind::from_stack(l,-1)};
    luabind::detail::add_overload(o,"__init",fn);
    lua_pop(l,1);
}
```

This will allow you to use any free function as a constructor *after* the class definition:

```
static void define_vector_class(lua_State *l)
{
    auto modMath = luabind::module_(l,"math");
    struct Vector
    {
        Vector()=default;
        float x,y,z;
    };
    auto defVec = luabind::class_<Vector>("Vector");
    modMath[defVec];

    // Define custom constructor taking three float arguments
    define_custom_constructor<Vector,[](float x,float y,float z) -> Vector {
        Vector v;
        v.x = x;
        v.y = y;
        v.z = z;
        return v;
    },float,float,float>(l); // Constructor parameter types have to be specified in template parameter list as well
}
```

Tested with the deboostified version of luabind (https://github.com/decimad/luabind-deboostified), but it should work with the regular version as well.